# Is there a way to remove certain part of object for the camera?

Tags: 3d-view, camera, clipping

Like for example, I'm putting the camera in a very small and confined space, like in the car, when i put the camera om place, some part of the car still shows up. is there a way i can hide some part of the car, preferablly keyframable?

The part of the window is still showing on this view, is there a way i can hide parts of the window[image]
or this part of frame of the car?[image]

Comment: Yes you can. E.g. by shader if you make a transparent shader with a mix node and keyframe the fac value of the mix node. Or you can use the mask modifier. Or you can use geometry nodes and e.g. delete geometry with selection of geometry and scene time node. And I am sure there are several more ways…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id place this as a comment but I can't cus Im new. Have you tried increasing the Camera's "Clip Start" (colloqually known as near plane) value?
[image]

Comment: oh i just realize you can keyframe the clipping lol. thanks